# libvirt API for domain migration

Tags: libvirt

Libvirt provide way to migrate guest domain, syntax as follows:

```
 syntax: virsh migrate GUESTNAME DEST-LIBVIRT-URI [HV-URI
```

I am wondering whether there's API to migrate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](http://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html#virDomainMigrate):

> virDomainPtr  virDomainMigrate    (virDomainPtr domain,
>                      virConnectPtr dconn,
>                      unsigned long flags,
>                      const char * dname,
>                      const char * uri,
>                      unsigned long bandwidth)
>
> Migrate the domain object from its current host to the destination
>   host given by dconn (a connection to the destination host).

Click the link for details.